# "." takes system32 path in jsp (tomcat) instead of current path

Tags: jsp, relative-path

The following is the code which i am using to create a text file in the same folder where this jsp file is present.

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
<% String nameOfTextFile = "./test.txt";
File file=new File(nameOfTextFile);
boolean exists = file.exists();
if(exists)
    {
    out.println("file exist");
    }
else
    {
    file.createNewFile();
    out.println("file created");
    }
%>
```

This jsp file is saved in tomcat/webapps/practice/ folder.

My question is that when i use this "./text.txt" as file path, it is taken as windows/system32/ path(when tomcat is run as admin) and tomcat/bin/ path(if tomcat is not run as admin).

Before 1 month i had used the same code to create a text file is the same folder and it worked fine, at that time i had win 7 as my OS, but now i ve win 8. I am not sure that this problem is because of the OS or some other thing.

Can anyone help...?

Comment: First of all, move all those codes to a Servlet. You shouldn't write Java code in JSP.

Comment: I tried that too, but it again has the same issue.